# SARIMA неправильно интерпретирует даты

Tags: python, matplotlib

Составляю прогноз по этому уроку https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3 и у меня возникла проблема в неправильном распределении дат по оси или неправильном отсчете. Формат дат меняла - не помогло. Предыдущий график с температурами вышел нормально, корреляция и т.д. тоже, т.е. проблема видимо в этой части кода или всё-таки в датах.

```
pred = results.get_prediction(start=('1990-02-01'), dynamic=False)
pred_ci = pred.conf_int()

ax = temp['1900':].plot(label='observed')
pred.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='One-step ahead Forecast', alpha=.7, figsize=(14, 4))
ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
                pred_ci.iloc[:,0],
                pred_ci.iloc[:,1], color='k', alpha=.2)
ax.set_xlabel('Дата')
ax.set_ylabel('Температура')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

UPD: если изменить значение с даты на число results.get_prediction(start=(1),dynamic=False), то линии сливаются в одну.
[image: UPD]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]